# How to get ID of element by click with symfony

Tags: symfony

I need to get the Id(thanks to the ID i will get all individual information, like email, phone number etc...)when i click on the name of people's database.

```
        <ul>
            {% for quote in agency.quotes %}
                <li><a href="{{ path('user_individualQuote') }}"> {{ quote.prospect.fullname }} 
                </a></li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
```

[image: 1]
This is the controller of the page :

```
/**
 * @Route("/individualQuote", name="user_individualQuote", methods={"GET","POST"})
 **/
public function getIndividualQuote(ProspectRepository $prospectRepository): Response
{


    return $this->render('user/_individualQuote.html.twig', [
        'prospect' => $prospectRepository->findAll(),

    ]);
}
```

My database:

[image: 2]

Exception log, info request:

[image: 3]

Comment: Maybe start [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/introduction/http_fundamentals.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks a lot like the `getIndividualQuote` route will return all the quotes.

One on `@ParamConverter` from `SensioFrameworkExtraBundle`. (Install with `composer require sensio/framework-extra-bundle`)

So, start there -

```
<?php

use namespace App\Entity\Prospect; // Or wherever your Prospect class is

/**
 * @Route("/individualQuote/{id}", name="user_individualQuote", methods={"GET","POST"})
 **/
public function getIndividualQuote(Prospect $prospect): Response
{
    return $this->render('user/_individualQuote.html.twig', [
        'prospect' => $prospect
    ]);
}
```

Key change is that the route relies on parsing an `$id` out of the url, and looking up a `Prospect` based on it's ID.
https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html#parameter-conversion

Then, you'll have to pass that ID into the URL by giving some extra parameters to the twig [`path` helper function](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/twig_reference.html#path). `{id: quote.prospect.id}`.

```
<ul>
     {% for quote in agency.quotes %}
         <li>
            <a href="{{ path('user_individualQuote', {id: quote.prospect.id}) }}"> {{ quote.prospect.fullname }}</a>
         </li>
     {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: the good new, is that i finally got the id in my url. But i got this error : "Argument 2 passed to App\Controller\UserController::getIndividualQuote() must be of the type int, string given"

Comment: What happens when you `{{ dump(quote.prospect.id) }}` somewhere in your twig template?

Comment: Might just have to convert to `int` with a filter. :) `            <a href="{{ path('user_individualQuote', {id: quote.prospect.id|int }) }}"> {{ quote.prospect.fullname }}</a>`

Comment: i tried the dump but the error block him. I tried to add the "|int'' too. same bug.

Comment: Don't know what "the error block him" means. :(

Comment: Also my url looking like this : http://127.0.0.1:8000/user/individualQuote/%7B%24id%7D?id=42

Comment: sorry, it means that the dump is probably hide by the exception

Comment: Got it, look like your controller's route method isn't pickin up on the `id` parameter. Let me amend my answer with a little more info!

Comment: ok thanks, i just edited my post (add a new screen of the info's request in the exception) if it can help

Comment: Hmm,. what about just putting `{{ path('user_individualQuote', quote.prospect.id) }}`?

Comment: same. Nothing change. I tried also to delete  "id:quote.prospect.id " , nothing change too.

Comment: Oh wait, the exception is almost the same('must be of the type array, int given, called in')I tried also to delete  "id:quote.prospect.id " , nothing change too.

Comment: You gotta start with the fundamentals article and work up to this, I'm afraid!

Comment: oh and the dump works and i got a normal Url (http://127.0.0.1:8000/user/individualQuote/42). It show me id of each name. Ok yeah i think so. The good thing is that i got the ID. I will try to find to problem. Thanks for your help.

Comment: it works finally i just change "ProspectRepository to Prospect $prospect" . Thanks a lot for your help @Cameron

Comment: That's what I did in my edited answer! Would you accept it? :)

Comment: Yes this is exactly what is in your edited answer !